# Using AVFoundation to record a video and add it directly to a table view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avkit

I am trying to make an app that allows me to record a video, display the preview of the video with the option to save it if the user chooses to do so (similar to snapchat), and once they hit send it will append to a message style chat window.

I've been able to record the video so far and then add it to the library, but I was wondering how to make it add directly into my app instead. I just can't seem to find resources I can make sense of anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please open given link below. Hopefully you will find what you are looking for.

https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit